# Change color of link of Lightbox link

Tags: css, hyperlink, lightbox

I use Lightbox Plus. In Lightbox.min.css i have changed the the linkcolors:

```
.lightbox  a{ 
color: #E74C3C;
}

.lightbox a:hover{
color:white;
}


.lightboxOverlay a:{ 
color: #E74C3C;
}

.lightboxOverlay a:hover{
color:white;
}
```

Problem: 
This approach does not change the color of the link under the Lightbox-image. The linkcolor stays #44aaee.

I did a search for that color in the source-files. I can’t find these default.
How can i change the linkcolor? Pls help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the link had 4four states

```
 a:link -  unvisited link
 a:visited -  visited link
 a:hover -  when  mouses over 
 a:active - when clicked
```

for link you should a:link

```
.lightboxOverlay a:link{ 
  color: red;
}
```

and for vidited a:visited

```
.lightboxOverlay a:visited{ 
  color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Works! Was a cache problem in the browser, Thanks!